# Select cells and replace contents with a formula

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post here, I have only done very limited vba before, so please forgive any mistakes!

I want to replace the contents of lots of cells with a formula relative to each cell.

the cells are all in the same column and currently contain a different formula which I want to replace with a new formula.

So far, I have been able to select the cells, but replacing the contents with the formula has eluded me! (There are lots more cells than these below, this is just as an example).

Here is what I've got so far:

```
Sub SelectSpecificCells()
    'selects all cells needing change
    Union(Range("A2, A5, A8, A11"), Range("A14, A17")).Select
End Sub
```

I want to select the following cells:

```
A2, A5, A8, A11, A14, A17
```

and change their contents to: 
=B2, =B5, =B8, =B11, =B14, =B17

Thanks for your help

Comment: After A2/B2, it is a requirement that every 3rd row is supposed to have the formula or can we have different intervals as well?

Comment: The pattern of the cells I want to select is regular and repeating. If it's easier to specify the pattern. I assumed it would be easier to specify the exact cells, but maybe not. The pattern of the formula would be the same ie: I want it to equal the cell to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific to what you're example is but maybe you can modify it to what you actually need.  A2 will have the formula "=$B$2".  This code would be placed inside a worksheet module.  If you wanted it in a regular module you'd have to change the "Me" to refer to a worksheet object or the Activesheet.

```
Sub test()
    Dim specificCells As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set specificCells = Union(Me.Range("A2, A5, A8, A11"), Me.Range("A14, A17"))

    For Each cell In specificCells
        cell.Value = "=" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Address
    Next
End Sub
```

New method after comments, adjust columns as needed:

```
Sub test()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim maxRow As Long

    row = 2
    maxRow = 17
    Do Until row > maxRow
        Me.Cells(row, 1).Value = "=" & Me.Cells(row, 2).Address
        row = row + 3
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, that worked perfectly, however, when I extend it to cover all of the cells I want it to apply to it doesn't work. Is there a maximum number of cells permitted within the ranges within union?

Comment: 3o is the max ranges you can use in union:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx

Comment: Does the pattern of specific cells repeat as it does in your example data (i.e. every third row)  Do to know the last row?  I can re-write it as a do loop in that case.

Comment: Hi Sobigen, yes it's a regular pattern all the way. A loop would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub test()
    Dim specificCells As Range
    Set specificCells = Union(Sheet4.Range("A2, A5, A8, A11"), Sheet4.Range("A14, A17"))
    specificCells.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDIRECT(""RC[1]"",FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]` ?